# how to split a string in a column field value of a table to multiple rows in select query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

table1

```
ID     ITEM
-----------------------
1      a|b|c
2      x|y|z
3      Q||S
4      ||||
5      J|K|Y|U
```

I want to insert  above ITEM to table2 as following  manner

table2

```
SLNO  ID   ITEMS
------------------------
1      1    a
2      1    b
3      1    c
4      2    x
5      2    y
6      2    z
7      3    Q
8      3    S
9      5    J
10     5    K
11     5    Y
12     5    U
```

so  i have used

```
INSERT INTO table2("ID","ITEMS")SELECT  ID,split_part("ITEM", '|',1) AS ITEMS FROM  table1
```

the problem is  split_part() need to specify a postion index,so it only split  and shows   first   positions  charaters
means,

```
ID  ITEMS
-----------
1   a
2   x
3   Q
5   J
```

So  how i  acheive above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the string to an array, then unnest that array:

```
select t.id, i.item
from the_table t
  cross join unnest(string_to_array(t.items, '|')) as i(item);
```

If you want to exclude the empty elements (e.g. in the line `4   ||||` you can use:

```
select t.id, i.item
from the_table t
  cross join unnest(string_to_array(t.items, '|')) as i(item)
where nullif(trim(i.item),'') is not null;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=962c83e10d8f3cfd5fd4e24ef6c83cad)